# Filter the output of a log file

Tags: linux, log-files, filter

**Question**
I've a log-File which display all console-logs of my website in the range of 10.Oct to 1.Nov, start with the logs of 10.Oct.
I need all logs from the range of 25.Oct until today.

The problem is that there is a huge exception. Every day I get an IOException over 21 lines and that for 6030 users, so there are about 126'600 lines of code which I won't see; per day.

So I need to filter the output to be able to read the logs normal again.

*What I already tried:*

```
less catalina.out | grep -v "java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL"
```

The log file is called *catalina.out*. But it don't my code don't hide the Exception, and I'm not able to scroll through the output.
So what i'm doing wrong? How should the code be?

---

**INFO about me**
I'm NOT familiar with Linux. I work in a support group, but today i'm alone and a website make some trouble. So I need to fix it by myself.
I google it now by 45 minutes but don't get it and the problem hurrys... So please be patient with me...

---

**INFO's about the problem**
Here all the facts and informations I know about my problem:
LOG-File Name: catalina.out
The whole IOException which I want to hide and get repeated 6030 times per day:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://secure.intern.webpage/userpicture/u117054.jpg
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1625)
        at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1037)
        at ch.sbb.wzuapp.business.batch.PersonCleanupNightlyJob.downloadUrl(PersonCleanupNightlyJob.java:270)
        at ch.sbb.wzuapp.business.batch.PersonCleanupNightlyJob.downloadPic(PersonCleanupNightlyJob.java:245)
        at ch.sbb.wzuapp.business.batch.PersonCleanupNightlyJob.doCleanup(PersonCleanupNightlyJob.java:76)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:64)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:53)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

The only thing which change in every exception is the picture-name. Everything else is always the same.

Comment: You'd better start with `cat catalina.out | grep -v "..." | less` which will restore scrolling ability. (First do the filtering, then aplpy `less` for viewing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, genuinely interesting problem, given that it's got to function at the end of a pipe.  There may be easier ways to do this, but I found this one worked (and it uses the sysadmin's [Swiss Army Chainsaw](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/S/Swiss-Army-chainsaw.html), perl):

```
tail -f catalina.out | perl -n -e '{ if (/^java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401/) { $ignore=1;} elsif ($ignore>=1 and $ignore<20) {$ignore++;} else {$ignore=0; print $_;}  }'
```

Basically, it steps through STDIN one line at a time, looking for the search string ("*^java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401*").  Until it's found, it prints each line as it comes in; once it's found, it starts counting to 20, once for each new line in, printing nothing while it counts; once the count gets to 20, it resets the count to zero and resumes printing each new line in.

**Edit**: No problem. Start with `tail -100000f catalina.out | ...`, or indeed a larger number yet if the logfile has more lines than that. If you don't want to see the new stuff as it's added, try

```
perl -n -e '{ if (/^java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401/) { $ignore=1;} elsif ($ignore>=1 and $ignore<20) {$ignore++;} else {$ignore=0; print $_;}  }' < catalina.out.
```

It's designed for use in a pipeline, so you can feed it whatever you want stripped, and you can send the output onto whatever needs it.  It's the UNIX way!

Comment: Why not ignoring all lines that foillow and begin with `     at ` instead of counting to 20 ? if the java call stack is different, your code breaks

Comment: Because the problem as specified by the OP was to ignore 21 lines which started with a given string.  If (s)he'd specified it differently, I'd've coded it differently, and that would be valid in that case.  I tend not to override the spec without good reason (ie, the spec is dumb); in this case, there's no reason to assume that the next line might not also begin with "     at", and be very important.

Comment: K.I.S.S. indeed.

Comment: When I run your code, don't read the whole log file. I just open it and get all NEW added lines. But I need the lines of the past 5 days, not these which are just added.

Comment: `+1`. It's a huge code. I think with your answer, I learned most :)

Comment: Please add `| less` to your code, so I'll be able to scroll and it is a working answer for me

Comment: You misunderstand; as the edit says, the command is designed to be include in a pipeline;  You could pipe it to `less`, sure, but you could also pipe it to `mail -s "Daily log entries" developers@example.com`, or `sort|uniq`, or any other UNIX tool that suits you.  It's up to you to decide what to do with STDOUT, not me, because it's your business need that will determine it.

Comment: Just realized that your answer is the only correct. Only your code ignores ONLY the io-exceptions. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

`grep` knows to take files as arguments. Please check the man.
You could use `egrep`, instead of `grep -e` (which is the same):

```
# egrep -v '^java.io|^\ {8}at' catalina.out | less
```

Comment: `+1` & accept. Works perfectly.

Comment: Other question. With grep "2013-10-25" I only get all the entrys of this day. How can I add this to your code? so using the opposite of -v ?

Comment: Since -v is applied for all grep command, you should pipe it into another grep. If you want to extend to more days: ...| egrep '2013-10-2[5-9]' | less.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to totally ignore exceptions you may want to try this :

```
cat catalina.out | grep -v -e '^java.io.IOExc' -e '       at ' | less
```

(replace the 7 spaces by a tab [Ctrl+V then Tab] if that doesn't work)

If need more removal, we'll start perl-grepping.

Comment: I ran it but it donesn't work. And I can't add a tab... the output is the same like the output with only `less catalina.out`. Do you need more information...?

Comment: `+1` With your code, I found the (for me) simplest way to solve my issue.

Comment: The working version of your code is `cat catalina.out | grep -v "java.io.IOException" | grep -v "at" | less`. Maybe you could edit your answer.

Comment: Using `-e`insterad of grep twice works the same. Plus, I wouldn't remove all lines containing "at" you might  miss a lot of them.